# How to save JSON sent by (Deno) server as dataclass model in Kotlin?

Tags: json, typescript, kotlin, response, deno

I am currently working on an application in the Kotlin programming language and I use Deno for the backend.

On the frontend I use Kotlin's programming language and I use the Fuel framework to send the request and to get a response.

```
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import com.digidex.digidex.models.Law
import com.digidex.digidex.models.LawGroup
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.Fuel
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.FuelManager
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.jackson.responseObject
import com.github.kittinunf.result.getOrNull

class LawService {
    init {
        FuelManager.instance.basePath = "http://144.12.31.126:3000/" // Local IP from Server
    }

    val laws = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Law>?>()
    val law_groups = MutableLiveData<MutableList<LawGroup>?>()

    fun loadLaws() {
        try {
            Fuel.get("law").responseObject<MutableList<Law>> { _, _, value ->
                laws.postValue(value.getOrNull())
            }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            println(e)
        }
    }

    fun loadLawGroups() {
        try {
            Fuel.get("law_groups").responseObject<MutableList<LawGroup>> { _, _, value ->
                law_groups.postValue(value.getOrNull())
            }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            println(e)
        }
    }
}
```

LawGroup model is defined as follows:

```
data class LawGroup(
    val name: String,
    val laws: MutableList<Law> = mutableListOf(),
    val number: Int,
    val size: Int = laws.size
)
```

### PROBLEM

When I start the server and try to retrieve JSON from the server via the emulator, I get null.

Comment: It's a simple get request, so, if you paste the url into the browser or make a request with fiddler or postman, do you get data or not?

Comment: Yes, I get data :)

Comment: If you get data, we can assume the backend is ok. So the client side (Kotlin) is not working. But you write so much about the backend, that's confusing and not relevant. I would remove the Deno and Typescript part from the question and just say I get this JSON (Example) via that get request and have a problem in Kotlin